# Postman gives 401 Unauthorized - Spring Boot & MYSQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, postman

Firstly: Yes, i know there's lots of this question already asked but no  one really helped me much.

Secondly:

-I've tried making a simple Auth with my username+password from MySQL credentials into the Postman but didn't worked

I've tried to remove the cookies from postman and that did not work.

Description:

link where i got the idea: [youtube link for this crud web app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IucFDX3RO9U&t=1705s)

I'm trying to develop an simple CRUD web app with Spring Boot, Lombok, JPA and Hibernate, MySQL.
Everytime i try to make a POST request into Postman it doesn't give me anything(401 Unathorized), as shown here:

[image: 1]

It only gives me "401 Unauthorized".

Of course when i run the project it gives me the DB shown in MYSQL

[image]

Here's the project content:(That YML file has nothing in it)

[image]

Here's some code:

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatechie
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = rooti
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server.port=9191
```

Also my configuration for the Controller:

```
package com.javatechie.crud.example.controller;

import com.javatechie.crud.example.entity.Product;
import com.javatechie.crud.example.service.ProductService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService service;

    @PostMapping("/addProduct")
    public Product addProduct(@RequestBody Product product){
        return service.saveProduct(product);

    }
    @PostMapping("/addProducts")
    public List<Product> addProduct(@RequestBody List<Product> product){

        return service.saveProducts(product);

    }
    @GetMapping("/products")
    public List<Product> findAllProducts(){
        return service.getProducts();


    }
    @GetMapping("/product/{id}")
    public Product findProductById(@PathVariable int id){
        return service.getProductById(id);
    }
    @GetMapping("/product/{name}")
    public Product findProductByName(@PathVariable String name){
        return service.getProductByName(name);
    }


    @PutMapping("/update")
    public Product updateProduct(@RequestBody Product product){
        return service.updateProduct(product);

    }
    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable int id){
        return service.deleteProduct(id);
    }


}
```

And also configuration for the "Service" that my CRUD web app wants to do. (for example i want to POST a request with "name","quantity","price" into my MYSQL DB)

```
package com.javatechie.crud.example.service;

import com.javatechie.crud.example.entity.Product;
import com.javatechie.crud.example.repository.ProductRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class ProductService {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository repository;

    public Product saveProduct(Product product){
        return repository.save(product);
    }

    public List<Product> saveProducts(List<Product> products){
        return repository.saveAll(products);
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }
    public Product getProductById(int id){
        return repository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    public Product getProductByName(String name){
        return repository.findByName(name);
    }
    public String deleteProduct(int id){
        repository.deleteById(id);
        return "product removed || "+id;
    }

    public Product updateProduct(Product product){
        Product existingProduct=repository.findById(product.getId()).orElse(product);
        existingProduct.setName(product.getName());
        existingProduct.setQuantity(product.getQuantity());
        existingProduct.setPrice(product.getPrice());
        return repository.save(existingProduct);
    }

}
```

Log from Spring Boot:

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:D:\intelj\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=51484:D:\intelj\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\spring-boot-crud-example\target\classes;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.5.0\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.5.0\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.7\spring-aop-5.3.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.6\aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.5.0\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\4.0.3\HikariCP-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.7\spring-jdbc-5.3.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.31.Final\hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.27.0-GA\javassist-3.27.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.22\byte-buddy-1.10.22.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.2.3.Final\jandex-2.2.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.3\dom4j-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.4\jaxb-runtime-2.3.4.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.4\txw2-2.3.4.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.12\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.5.1\spring-data-jpa-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.5.1\spring-data-commons-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.7\spring-orm-5.3.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.7\spring-context-5.3.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.7\spring-tx-5.3.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.7\spring-beans-5.3.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.30\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.7\spring-aspects-5.3.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client\2.5.0\spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.5.0\spring-boot-starter-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.5.0\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.14.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.14.1\log4j-api-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.30\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.28\snakeyaml-1.28.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\sun\mail\jakarta.mail\1.6.7\jakarta.mail-1.6.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.5.0\spring-security-config-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8\1.5.0\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.5.0\kotlin-stdlib-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\annotations\13.0\annotations-13.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.5.0\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7\1.5.0\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.5.0\spring-security-core-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.7\spring-expression-5.3.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-oauth2-client\5.5.0\spring-security-oauth2-client-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-oauth2-core\5.5.0\spring-security-oauth2-core-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.5.0\spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\nimbusds\oauth2-oidc-sdk\9.3.3\oauth2-oidc-sdk-9.3.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\github\stephenc\jcip\jcip-annotations\1.0-1\jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\nimbusds\content-type\2.1\content-type-2.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\nimbusds\lang-tag\1.5\lang-tag-1.5.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-oauth2-jose\5.5.0\spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\nimbusds\nimbus-jose-jwt\9.8.1\nimbus-jose-jwt-9.8.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.5.0\spring-boot-starter-web-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.5.0\spring-boot-starter-json-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.12.3\jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.12.3\jackson-annotations-2.12.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.12.3\jackson-core-2.12.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.12.3\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.12.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.12.3\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.12.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.12.3\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.12.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.5.0\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.46\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.46\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.46.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.46\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.46.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.7\spring-web-5.3.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.7\spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.5.0\spring-boot-devtools-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.5.0\spring-boot-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.5.0\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.25\mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.20\lombok-1.18.20.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.4.7\json-smart-2.4.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\net\minidev\accessors-smart\2.4.7\accessors-smart-2.4.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\9.1\asm-9.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.7\spring-core-5.3.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.7\spring-jcl-5.3.7.jar" com.javatechie.crud.example.SpringBootCrudExampleApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.0)

2021-06-03 18:13:32.004  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.c.e.SpringBootCrudExampleApplication : Starting SpringBootCrudExampleApplication using Java 1.8.0_291 on DESKTOP-ECK0851 with PID 2216 (D:\spring-boot-crud-example\target\classes started by User in D:\spring-boot-crud-example)
2021-06-03 18:13:32.007  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.c.e.SpringBootCrudExampleApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-06-03 18:13:32.056  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-06-03 18:13:32.056  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-06-03 18:13:32.122  WARN 2216 --- [kground-preinit] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2021-06-03 18:13:32.697  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-06-03 18:13:32.781  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 59 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-06-03 18:13:33.766  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9191 (http)
2021-06-03 18:13:33.780  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-06-03 18:13:33.780  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.46]
2021-06-03 18:13:33.891  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-06-03 18:13:33.891  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1834 ms
2021-06-03 18:13:34.188  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-06-03 18:13:34.256  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.31.Final
2021-06-03 18:13:34.381  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-06-03 18:13:34.477  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-06-03 18:13:34.861  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-06-03 18:13:34.877  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2021-06-03 18:13:35.454  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-06-03 18:13:35.468  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-06-03 18:13:35.904  WARN 2216 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-06-03 18:13:36.505  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: ae5d43ed-6daf-4bd0-af28-6a3556efa3d9

2021-06-03 18:13:36.662  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7c8e2912, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@52505b33, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@50e12e2, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@6154ed39, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3dc302ae, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@47e4cf9b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@6d4c7b4a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@3b11a857, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@5de87cc1, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@26fe4b74, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@72836232, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2581c580, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@39d23724, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6b35fce7, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@60b34615]
2021-06-03 18:13:36.724  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-06-03 18:13:36.755  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9191 (http) with context path ''
2021-06-03 18:13:36.764  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.c.e.SpringBootCrudExampleApplication : Started SpringBootCrudExampleApplication in 5.248 seconds (JVM running for 5.803)
2021-06-03 18:13:36.765  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
2021-06-03 18:13:36.767  INFO 2216 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
2021-06-03 18:14:15.319  INFO 2216 --- [nio-9191-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-06-03 18:14:15.319  INFO 2216 --- [nio-9191-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-06-03 18:14:15.320  INFO 2216 --- [nio-9191-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

POM.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.javatechie</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-crud-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-crud-example</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Are you using Spring Security, do you have a security configuration and if so could you please share it? Could you also share the logs from your application when you get the 401 response?

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana I'm not having any  security configuration on my project. I have not mentioned that, very sorry. also the log from application: https://imgur.com/a/78mYIWB

Comment: Do you have a Spring Security dependency? Something like `spring-boot-starter-security`? Can you share the logs from the running Spring application, not Postman?

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana i've edited my post with the log from my Spring (using IntelJ IDE) and also no, i don't hve a security dependency. From the tutorial i've posted it doesn't use one(i've puted even the link). So i don't know why it doesn't work for me, making a POST request into postman.

Comment: The logs show that you are using Spring Security `Using generated security password: ae5d43ed-6daf-4bd0-af28-6a3556efa3d9`. The first step would be to figure out where the Security dependency is coming from. Feel free to share your pom.xml if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana Thanks a lot for figuring out what may be the problem. Thanks a lot for the tip. I've edited with my POM.XML. I think from there it comes the Spring security. Thanks again for trying to help me.

Comment: It's coming from the `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` dependency. If you aren't using OAuth2 feel free to remove that dependency.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana i've removed the dependecy from my xml file but still it gives me the same thing.(401 unathorized) from postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault from the start: It was automatically checked from the checkbox in IntelliJ "Spring Security". I unchecked it and it all worked.
[image]